# Custom JS-DOS DosBox.conf implementation issue

Tags: javascript, dosbox

Failure when trying to implement custom dosbox.conf
inside js-dos installation.

For the life of me, I simply CANNOT figure out how the hell 
to overwrite default js-dos dosbox.conf configuration file 
whith a custom made one. I've tried everything I can find,

It needs to be able to extract/download remotely specific 
games

then use it's own dosbox.conf as per game.

the attached html code works fine in itself,
but does not work with custom dosbox.conf.

I would like it to dynamically load game data and dosbox.conf

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Digger js-dos 6.22</title>
  <script src="https://js-dos.com/6.22/current/js-dos.js"></script>
  <style>
  canvas {
     width: 640px;
     height: 400px;
   }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="jsdos"></canvas>
  <script>
   Dos(document.getElementById("jsdos"), { 
      wdosboxUrl: "https://js-dos.com/6.22/current/wdosbox.js" 
      }).ready((fs, main) => {
  fs.extract("http://www.unbored.be/games/calgames.zip").then(() => {
     main(["-c", "calgames"])
     });
    });
  </script>
  </body>

 </html>
```

Doesn't load dosbox.conf whatever I try.

Answer (score 1):

To do this:

- Download dosbox.conf with XMLHttpRequest.
- Write downloaded dosbox.conf to dosbox file system.
- Run game with custom dosbox.conf ("-c", "path-to-dosbox.conf")

Probably your code will look like this:

```
function get(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            resolve(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.onerror = reject;
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.send();
    });
}

const confPromise = get("http://www.unbored.be/<...>/dosbox.conf");

Dos(document.getElementById("jsdos"), {
    wdosboxUrl: "https://js-dos.com/6.22/current/wdosbox.js"
}).ready((fs, main) => {
    confPromise.then((conf) => {
        fs.extract("http://www.unbored.be/games/calgames.zip").then(() => {
        fs.createFile("dosbox.conf", conf);
            main(["-conf", "dosbox.conf", "-c", "DOOM.EXE"])
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't know if it worked for the OP, but it certainly doesn't work for me.

Comment: @deathwombat what exactly didn't work? I checked this snipped and it works fine.

Comment: @caiiiycuk where can I find an example default dosbox.conf?

Comment: @deathwombat https://js-dos.com/#js-dos-622-faq-how-to-override-dosboxconf

Comment: @caiiiycuk I don't remember if I was ever able to get that code to work or not, but what I'm doing now works perfectly. I guess 'fs.createFile("dosbox.conf", conf)' wasn't working, because I replaced the second argument with the text of my overridden config file. It looks like 'fs.createFile("dosbox.conf", \`various sections and key-value pairs\`)'. You have to use the "left apostrophe" character (U+0060 : GRAVE ACCENT) from the key where Shift produces a tilde in order to include multiple lines of text.